# Mouseover is causing image to (seemingly) disappear instead of doing function

Tags: javascript, html

I ran it through a syntax validator but it didn't indicate any errors. The image is only supposed to grow larger with a box shadow. I tried another mouseover event with just a simple alert instead and that worked perfectly fine so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.style = "box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black";
    this.width = "110px"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.width = "110px";` should be: `this.style.width = "110px";`

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.style = "box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black";
    this.style.width = "110px";
});
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
```

Additionally, you should attempt to avoid setting inline styles and instead apply/remove CSS classes, which a easier to manage and, in this case, can completely remove the need for JavaScript through the use of the [CSS `:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

```css
#image:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  width:110px;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">
```

Comment: @alex.b You're welcome. Please consider marking this as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `style`

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    this.style.boxShadow = "2px 2px 2px black";
    this.style.width = "110px";
});
```